# Validation with Regular Expressions

Tags: php, javascript, regex, validation

I am setting up a payment page, I am a designer and not a developer. So I have been having some problems. The payment company gave me some direction, however they included validation using regular expressions for the field 'AMOUNT'. I have researched 'regular expressions' but have been unsuccessful adding more to the 'checkfor' that they provided. I need simple validation, just three required fields, 'name', CUST_NUM and 'terms'(which is a checkbox).Can anyone enlighten me?

```
<form action=http://rcehholidaytrust.com/account/redirectoffresponsepage.php method=post onSubmit="return checkform()">
    <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td><div align="right"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Name </font></div></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" size="48" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div align="right"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Acc. No.</font></td>
            <td><label for="client"></label>
            <input name="CUST_NUM" type="text" id="client" size="48" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div align="right">Payment €</div></td>
            <td><label for="AMOUNT"></label>
            <input name="AMOUNT" type="text" id="AMOUNT" size="47" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div align="right"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Address</font></div></td>
            <td><textarea name="address" wrap="virtual" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div align="right"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Telephone</font></div></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="telephone" size="48" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p align="right"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">Email</font></p></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" size="48" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div align="right"></div></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" />
            <label for="terms">Agree to terms and conditions</label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type=submit value="Proceed to secure server">
</form>


<script>
function checkform()
{
    var amount = document.getElementById("AMOUNT").value;
    if(amount.match(/^[0-9]{1,6}\.[0-9]{2}$/))
    {
        return true;
    }
    // else if(amount.match(/^[0-9]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}$/))
    //{
    //                return true;
    //}
    else
    {
        alert("Please enter a valid amount i.e. 12.34EUR = 12.34");
        return false;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated. It does not work somehow, if I hit submit, it submits without checking any validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `test` for your problem:

**For All Validations**

```
function checkform()
{
    var reg=/^[0-9]{1,6}\.[0-9]{2}$/;

    var status=true;
    if(!reg.test(document.getElementById('AMOUNT').value) && document.getElementById('AMOUNT').indexOf('.')==-1 )
    // adding 1 more ending brace
    {
       status=false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('client').value=="" || document.getElementById('name').value=="")
    // change here client in place of CUST_NAME
    {
        status=false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('terms').checked==false)
    {
        status=false;
    }
    if(status==false)
       alert("Please check all fields");
    return status;
}
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/zUQK9/

Comment: Thanks for your help, it submits without checking the validation? Not sure why?

Comment: `alert status` what you get in it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you can see it here, http://rcehholidaytrust.com/account/request-stack.php

Comment: @user2314514 Check the above answer once I have made changes.

Comment: Thanks Rohan your help is appreciated, just be aware also that the decimel point requirement in the 'AMOUNT' field is important. It was this piece of code that started the problems for me.

Comment: @user2314514 Now check the above.

Comment: Rohan, it is getting closer. It now requires that I fill in 'terms' and 'CUST_NUM' but it is disregarding the 'AMOUNT' variable. I need the 'AMOUNT' to ask for decimal point.

Comment: This line `document.getElementById('AMOUNT').indexOf('.')==-1` checks that you should enter `decimal point`. Also try `&&` in place of `||` , check my answer

Comment: Hi Rohan, I replaced '||' with && and the validation stopped working, I realise the document.getElementById('AMOUNT') checks the decimal, but for some reason it does not work. I have it posted online if you'd like to see http://rcehholidaytrust.com/account/request-stack.php  It will submit if I fill in Account Number and click the checkbox, but it does not require Payment(AMOUNT)with decimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkform()
{
    var checks=0;
    var amount = document.getElementById("AMOUNT").value;
    if(amount.match(/^[0-9]{1,6}\.[0-9]{2}$/))
    {
        checks++;
    }

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    if(name != '') //if you want to check if it's not empty, you could also use: name.match(/^[\w\s\d]+$/) to check if name contains any combination of numbers, chars and spaces.
    {
        checks++;
    }

    if(document.getElementById("terms").checked) 
    {
        checks++;
    }

    if(checks==3){return true;}
    alert("Please enter a valid amount i.e. 12.34EUR = 12.34");
    return false;
}
```

This should work, didn't test it tho so tell me if anything isn't working!

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated. It does not work somehow, if I hit submit, it submits without checking any validation.

Comment: Any ideas what might be the problem? I posted your code on this page.http://rcehholidaytrust.com/account/request-stack1.php It does not ask for any validation.

Comment: sorry I was out yesterday. try to do a couple of `alert()` inside the checkform function to see how is it behaving. I would suggest doing some `alert(checks)` before and after each of the ifs.

Comment: by the way, I tried the link you provided and it correctly displays the "Please enter a valid ammount..."